# Adding the navigation drawer to my app in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I've just started working on Android Studio, everything is relatively new to me. I added a new navigation drawer activity to my application, but it doesn't seem to have the toggle button on my bar. I would I go about to enable it. I can see inside the navigation drawer's class that there is already code for toggling. I've searched the internet for a really long time, and all I've found are either tutorial of making the navigation drawer first as their starting template, or creating it diretly from the main activity from scratch.

My Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.top_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id == R.id.info) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Information.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

The Navigation drawer(has not been touched):

```
public class navigation_drawer extends AppCompactActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigation_drawer, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

after

```
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the quick reply. I added 
'getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);'
 after 
'setSupportActionBar(toolbar);' but there is still nothing on my bar. I then added 
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 under the onCreate method in my main activity and it showed up but was unable to be clicked. Do I need to extended my navigationdrawer from my main?

Comment: did you also add 'getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);'

Comment: Yes, In the end, I started a new project, choosing the drawer template, and just put all my code on the main activity of the new project. I think my problem is being unable to connect the two java files in the original project. I had all my app code on my main, and all the navigation code on another java file.